# Why is my programmatically created user missing from the Welcome screen?

Tags: security, winapi

I have a program that creates a Windows user account using the [NetUserAdd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370649(VS.85).aspx) API which is [suggested by Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/119671win32).  The user is created successfully, and I can log in as that user.

However, on Windows XP, the newly-created user is missing from the Welcome screen.  If I disable the Welcome screen, I can log in as the new user by typing the user name in direcly.

What property of the account I create causes it to be omitted from the Welcome screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you could do is add the username as a  value to the registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList

Use the username (As a REG_DWORD) and a value of 1 to show the user and 0 to hide.

Comment: This suggestion worked to get the account shown on the Welcome screen.